# Почему возникает ошибка в dreamweaver (must be lowercase)

Tags: html, html5

**Пример кода:**

```
<header>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <nav>
    <Ul>
      <li><a href="1">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="2">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="3">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="4">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="5">5</a></li>
    </Ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <h1>Основная часть</h1>
  <section>
    <h2>Заголовок 2</h2>
    <!--Отзывы клиентов, не уверены что это похоже на статью-->
  </section>

  <article>
    <h2>Заголовок статьи</h2>
    <p>Текст <mark>статьи</mark></p>
    <time datetime="2017-01-17T12:00">17 Января 2017</time>
    <!--Статья, контент-->
  </article>

</main>

<aside>
  <section>
    <h3>Ссылки</h3>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h3>Реклама</h3>
  </section>
</aside>

<footer>

</footer>
```

Суть вопроса, что на тегах Ul, ASIDE возникает ошибка что элемент должен быть строчным (must be lowercase). Стили css не используются, разве эти элементы не являются изначально строчными или же все таки?

Comment: Это больше похоже на ошибку валидации: мне мол не нравится, что вы пишите названия тегов с заглавной буквы.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, вопрос решён.надеюсь это только в Dw, потому что я обычно придерживаюсь такого стиля для удобства